# freertos global variable inside isr

Tags: scheduled-tasks, stm32, multitasking, freertos

I'm new to RTOS and having some troubles understanding a strange behavior:

I have a STM32 microcontroller running FreeRTOS and an RTC interrupt running, too.
The RTC interrupt just updates a `volatile uint32_t` variable named `SystemTime`:

```
void HAL_RTC_AlarmAEventCallback(RTC_HandleTypeDef *hrtc) {
  UNUSED(hrtc);
  SystemTime++;
}
```

Additionally, I have another task that runs every 100 mS.
It just prints the `SystemTime` value if it has changed.

```
static void ToggleLEDThread(void const *argument) {
  (void) argument;
  static uint32_t ost;
  uint32_t tst;

  for (;;) {
#if 0
    tst = SystemTime;
    if (ost != tst) {
      xprintf("<%d>\n", tst);
      ost = tst;
    }
#else
    if (ost != SystemTime) {
      xprintf("<%d>\n", SystemTime);
      ost = SystemTime;
    }
#endif
    vTaskDelay(100);
  }
}
```

It works as expected if `#if 1` (using a temporary variable), but when `#if 0`, the code runs ok for some time before it stops printing and after a few seconds starts to print again.

There is another task that prints some other values once a second.

Output when it's working:

```
V:1139  O:1091
<35>
V:1139  O:1123
<36>
V:1140  O:1154
<37>
V:1140  O:1186
<38>
V:1139  O:1218
<39>
V:1139  O:1249
<40>
V:1139  O:1281
<41>
V:1139  O:1313
<42>
V:1139  O:1344
<43>
V:1139  O:1376
<44>
V:1139  O:1408
<45>
V:1139  O:1439
<46>
V:1140  O:1471
<47>
V:1139  O:1503
<48>
V:1139  O:1535
<49>
V:1139  O:1566
<50>
V:1140  O:1598
<51>
V:1139  O:1630
<52>
V:1139  O:1661
```

Output when the problem happens:

```
V:1139  O:1091
<35>
V:1139  O:1123
<36>
V:1140  O:1154
<37>
V:1140  O:1186
<38>
V:1139  O:1218
<39>
V:1139  O:1249
<40>
V:1139  O:1281
<41>
V:1139  O:1313
<42>
V:1139  O:1344
V:1139  O:1376
V:1139  O:1408
V:1139  O:1439
V:1140  O:1471
V:1139  O:1503
V:1139  O:1535
V:1139  O:1566
<50>
V:1140  O:1598
<51>
V:1139  O:1630
<52>
V:1139  O:1661
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The code in both instances looks ok to me from a quick look. Maybe add another line of debug to print the system time every time the task runs. Maybe the problem lies elsewhere and the task is getting blocked and not running every 100ms as you think?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (ost != SystemTime) {
    xprintf("<%d>\n", SystemTime);
    ost = SystemTime;
}
```

Here. While you are printing your SystemTimeValue, interrupt occur and your value is incremented. After that you equate a variable **ost** to *modified* variable SystemTime. Thats why next round is missing and code does not printing new time value.

Just a guess

Answer (score 1):

Use [vTaskDelayUntil](http://www.freertos.org/vtaskdelayuntil.html) instead. This will take into account the time wasted sending over UART. SystemTime is a critical section care with that.

Answer (score -1):

Try giving the task that prints SystemTime higher priority than your other task. The #if 0 case I think is the correct implementation because in the other case SystemTime may be modified between checking it and storing it.

Comment: I think it is just the other way around: If setting `#if 0`, the lower code variant will run, which accesses `SystemTime` several times without protection, which may just miss those increments that happen in between.